# Is there a way to check two different by.css() attributes in the same element() check in protractor?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, protractor

I am testing elements in a grid on an HTML page with protractor. There are 2 columns and multiple rows. Currently my code is

```
browser.element(by.css('div[data-row="1"]')).element(by.css('.widget-toggle-btn')).click();
```

HTML:

```
<div data-row="1" data-col="0" ....other stuff here>
    ....(other elements)....
</div>
<div data-row="1" data-col="1" ....other stuff here>
    ....(other elements)....
</div>
```

but as you can see there are 2 columns in data-row 1. Luckily the one I want is in 'data-col="0"', but I don't see a way to get to the toggle-btn that's in 'data-col="1"'. The grid is symmetrical so all elements are the same in the view, but clicking on the buttons give different results. Is there a way for me to designate two attributes in a by.css() locator or do I have to do it a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just add a new condition in the square brackets:

```
div[data-row=1][data-col=1]
```

You can actually join the chain of selectors in a single selector:

```
$('div[data-row=1][data-col=1] .widget-toggle-btn').click();
```

`$()` is a shortcut to `element(by.css())`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I feel like I'm going to a constant source of questions for you to answer :\ lol

Comment: @amiller956 thank you for the interesting questions!